# What does view-response.js in Chrome do?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, httpresponse

When loading a page (`200 OK` response header), I received an error in the [HTTP response add-on for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/http-response-browser/?src=api):

> [Exception... "File error: Not found" nsresult: "0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)" location: "JS frame :: **chrome://view-response/content/view-response.js** :: sendRequest :: line 186" data: no]

What does that file do? (Contents pasted into [JSBin here](http://jsbin.com/iyucur/1/edit), notice how semicolons are missing.)

I was able to open it in Firefox and not just Chrome (but not Opera and IE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an error with the plugin internal code, nothing to do with your code. The chrome:// is a little misleading, it's nothing to do with Google Chrome, Mozilla refers to elements of their UI engine as the "chrome".

The error is specifically around the line:

```
xhr.send(valueOfElement("body-textarea"))
```

Which is an ajax request initiated on this line:

```
xhr.open(valueOfElement("method-select"), valueOfElement("uri-input"), true)
```

...and since you are getting NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND I presume the that URL return by the function call `valueOfElement("uri-input")` is returning a 404 or may be an invalid URL.

The lack of semi-colons in the JS file is (IMO) bad practice, but nothing to do with the error.

Long story short: ignore the error, there's nothing you can do about it except for add some error handling and rebuild the plugin package, which you probably can't do in a meaningful way unless you wrote the plugin.

It has nothing to do with your site code.

Comment: Thanks, by "plugin", do you mean the Firefox add-on?

Comment: @Baumr Yes indeed. The `chrome://view-response` refers to the plugin's "chrome" section of the package, and the remaining path is just a path to the file. The fact that this is a `chrome://` URL is the giveaway for the problem here, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Tutorial/The_Chrome_URL for a basic overview of what it's doing, although you really don't need to know any of that for your purposes (you only need to know about it if you are developing a Mozilla add-on)